# Using a Javascript Variable in Sparql update

Tags: javascript, node.js, sparql, ontology, protege

I am using my Nodejs app to Run(Sending HTTP Post) Sparql updates on my Ontology model. Now I have a variable 'seconds' in my code that stores an integer value. Now How do I include that variable to my query.

```js
var request = require('request');
var querystring = require('querystring');

var seconds = ROB_8_StopSeconds-ROB_8_StartSeconds;
var myquery2 = querystring.stringify({
   update: "PREFIX test:<http://www.semanticweb.org/muhammad/ontologies/2017/2/untitled-ontology-14#> insert {[] test:Actual_Production_Time ?s; test:hasValue_ROB1 ?p; test:hasTime ?now.} where {values (?s ?p ) {(test:Actual_Production_Time 2000)} bind (now() as ?now)}"
   });

request.post({headers: {'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
    url: 'http://localhost:3030/DS-1/?' + myquery2},
        function(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
     console.log('successful update');
     //console.log(body);
    } else {
     console.log(response.statusCode)
     console.warn(error);
    }
   });
```

Now in my query as you can see I am sending 2000 but i want to send the variable 'seconds' instead of 2000. How can I achieve this?. And Secondly, will my model be able to extract that integer value from the variable 'seconds'.

P.s: I have searched the answer in dotNetRDF Documentation(https://github.com/dotnetrdf/dotnetrdf/wiki) but I couldn't find it thr.

Comment: Is is not a simply string manipulation in Javascript? Or what is the problem? You want to use the value of the Javascript variable `seconds` in the SPARQL query string, or not?

Comment: Since version 4.0, Node.js supports [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Comment: Yes I want to use the value of Javascript variable 'seconds' in my Sparql query string. Is thr any syntax or style to use the variable in the SPARQL Query string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by simply concatenating the variable between the strings outside the querystring.stringify().

```js
var seconds = ROB_8_StopSeconds - ROB_8_StartSeconds;
  
    abc = "PREFIX test:<http://www.semanticweb.org/muhammad/ontologies/2017/2/untitled-ontology-14#> insert {[] test:Actual_Production_Time ?s; test:hasValue_ROB1 ?p; test:hasTime ?now.} where {values (?s ?p ) {(test:Actual_Production_Time "+seconds+")} bind (now() as ?now)}";
   var myquery2 = querystring.stringify({
    update: abc
   });
```

I was trying to do the concatenating inside the querystring.stringify() which is wrong.